# MSSQL choose top 2 ranked for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Hi I have a table that looks like this

| StudentID | ParentID | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 5 |
| 1 | 16 | 6 |
| 2 | 21 | 1 |
| 2 | 22 | 2 |
| 3 | 31 | 1 |
| 3 | 37 | 7 |
| 3 | 38 | 8 |
| 4 | 41 | 1 |
| 4 | 42 | 2 |

So I want to pull only the top 2 ranks per student the out come will look like:

| StudentID | ParentID | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 | 5 |
| 2 | 21 | 1 |
| 2 | 22 | 2 |
| 3 | 31 | 1 |
| 3 | 37 | 7 |
| 4 | 41 | 1 |
| 4 | 42 | 2 |

What would be the best way to do this? What makes it complicated is that every student has a parent ranked 1 but not every student has a parent ranked 2. What sql statement would I use to pull just the next ranked parent after 1?

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by studentid order by rank) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Under some circumstances, it might be faster to use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rank in (select top (2) t2.rank
                 from t t2
                 where t2.studentid = t.studentid
                 order by rank asc
                ) ;
```

I think this might have better performance if there were few students that had lots of ranks per student and you had an index on `studentid, rank`.

Comment: Depends on indexing also